# Perl workweek conversion is incorrect

Tags: perl, date, datetime-format

I'm faced a weird problem.
I have date in form of  **Tue Feb 25 00:20:13 2014**.
my task is to calculate the week number and the week day.
I tried the following

```
use Time::Piece;

my $date="Tue Feb 25 00:20:13 2014";
my $db_date=Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
my $ww=$db_date->strftime("%W.%w-%Y);
print $ww;
```

When I run the script I get the output as

```
08.2-2014
```

which is wrong, the expected output is

```
09.2-2014
```

I want to know where did i go wrong?
pls help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the "%W" strftime() conversion.  Time::Piece doesn't specify the meaning of "%W", but the documentation for the equivalent C function says that "%W" starts counting with the first week that contains a Monday.  It sounds like you want the ISO 8601 week number, which starts counting with the first week that contains at least four days, in which case the "%V" conversion should do what you want.

Comment: hi @Mark.. I tried using "%V" but I'm not getting any output displayed. Its just blank.

Comment: Odd.  `$ww=$db_date->strftime("%V.%w-%Y");` works for me, using Perl 5.16.3 on Linux.

Comment: I'm using Padre IDE, Perl <5.16.3>

Comment: Try using sprintf() and the Time::Piece accessor methods to bypass any issues with strftime(): `$ww=sprintf("%02d.%d-%d", $db_date->week(), $db_date->day_of_week(), $db_date->year);`

Comment: Time::Piece does say the strfime is the same as POSIX::strftime, which says "If you want your code to be portable, your format (fmt) argument should use only the conversion specifiers defined by the ANSI C standard (C89, to play safe). These are `aAbBcdHIjmMpSUwWxXyYZ%`..."; presumably damseldeebi is using a perl using msvcrt, which doesn't support `%V`